# How to calculate average number of days between dates in date order

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, postgresql-9.4

Table contains order dates

```
create table orderdate ( orderdate date not null )
```

How to calculate average days between dates in table.
Difference needs to be calculated between neighbour dates in date order to find average number of dates between orders.

Adding this number to last order date produces estimated next order date.

For example if table contains

```
2019-09-10
2019-09-21
2019-09-25
```

differences between orders are 10 and 4 days  and average difference is

```
(10+4)/2 = 7 days
```

next order esimated date is 2019-09-25 + 7 = 2019-10-02

Using

```
PostgreSQL 9.4.19
```

Comment: 4 is 25-21. Difference needs to be calculated between neighbour dates in date order. I updated question

Comment: Ah ok, I misunderstood. I thought you want to get an average date...

Comment: I updated question again to provide more information. I need to get estimated next order date based on dates from previous orders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select ( max(date) - min(date) ) / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0) as avg_duration
from t;
```

The number of gaps is one less than the count.  Hence the average is the total duration divided by the number of gaps.

Comment: This does not use all order dates. I need to get average number of days between tow dates in date order. Adding this to last order date produces estrimate of nextr order date which is what I need. I updated question.

Comment: Sure, this works: AVG(10, 21, 25) = MAX() - MIN() / (COUNT() - 1) = 25 - 10 / (3 - 1) = 7.5

Comment: @Andrus . . . This does work.  The answer even explains how it works.

Comment: Average number of days between orders depends on all order dates. Your query does not use all orderr dates in table. It uses only first and last date. So it cannot produce correct result. Laurenz Albe answer worked.

Comment: @Andrus . . . This is simply not true.  The average number depends on the first and last dates and the number of gaps -- that is the way that mathematics works.  Try it out.

Comment: Thank you. Probably you are right. I marked your answer as answer since it is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

First calculate the difference between adjacent dates, then take the average:

```
SELECT avg(CAST(days_between AS double precision))
FROM (SELECT orderdate
             - (lag(orderdate) OVER (ORDER BY orderdate)) AS days_between
      FROM orderdate) AS q;
```

I cast to `double precision`, because the difference between two `date`s is an `integer`.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. However I marked Gordon Linoff answer as answer since it is simpler.